# Plot data points and line between them in different colour?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the given points and interpolating line between them in different colour.

```
ListLinePlot[{{-0.5`, 3.41613`}, {-0.45`, 0.659892`}, {-0.425`,  0.574592`}, {-0.4`, 0.510328`}, {-0.375`, 0.457582`}, {-0.35`, 0.412097`}, {-0.325`, 0.371589`}, {-0.3`, 0.334686`}, {-0.275`,  0.300496`}, {-0.25`, 0.268405`}, {-0.225`, 0.237965`}, {-0.2`,  0.208843`}, {-0.175`, 0.180779`}, {-0.15`, 0.153564`}, {-0.125`, 0.127028`}, {-0.1`, 0.101024`}, {-0.075`, 0.0754275`}, {-0.05`,  0.0501257`}, {-0.025`, 0.0250156`}}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Using the command `ListLinePlot` gives me the points and line with same colour. Is there a way to plot the points, say in red, and the line, say in blue?

Comment: Did you try to add `PlotStyle->{Red}, PlotMarkers->{Blue}`?

Comment: @Rom38 Thank you.